# How to Redirect To Rewritten Url

Tags: .htaccess

Guys i have this following code which is does its job quite good but there is one problem when i go example.com/ara.php?name=hey it doesnt redirect to 
example.com/pdf-ara/hey i need help.

but when i go to example.com/pdf-ara/hey it works

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pdf-ara/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)$  ara.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Sorry, but we cannot somehow magically guess what changes you made and took back. So how do you expect an answer from us? Please revise the question (there is an "edit" link below it) and add more details: what requests succeed, what requests lead to an error? What does your http server's error log file say? What changes did you make?

Comment: this must be coincidence i was just looking at your profile thought maybe you can help i'll edit

Comment: it wasnt a problem its just my shared hosting detects it very late i changed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now your question is why the internal rewriting works, but no external redirection is performed, right?

Well the answer is: you did not implement any such rule. Take a look at this appraoch:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=([\d\w-_]+)$
RewriteRule ^/?ara\.php$ /pdf-ara/%1 [R=301]

RewriteRule ^/?pdf-ara/([\d\w-_]+)$ /ara.php?name=$1 [END]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported [END] flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older [L] flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's DOCUMENT_ROOT folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: hey thanks for your interest so i've applied this piece of rule
`<form class="form-inline" action="ara.php" method="get">` and this is my form
but still doesnt redirect

Comment: @EnginYücelen I have no idea what that is about. The question you asked is about rewriting rules.

Comment: ok i'll let you know if i manage with the information you gave it to me thanks again